# Cant fix the Intent Scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, url-scheme

I want an intent that; If the application is installed goes to the app. If it isn't installed it will go to the store.

Now is Nos.nl a news app and I try it as a test but I can't fix it.

This is what I use:
intent://nos.nl#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;package=nl.nos.app;scheme=http;end

But it always goes directly to the store.

Answer (score 1):

It's required to add the [CATEGORY_BROWSABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_BROWSABLE) category to all intent filters which should open the app from a browser.